# How do I change text in a-frame using a-animations?

Tags: aframe

For example, I have some text "Hello" floating about in the scene, on mousing over it I want the text to change to "Hi"

Right now, when I try to use an animation, the text just disappears off, instead of changing.
Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

[Here is an example using JavaScript to change text on mouseover.](http://codepen.io/bryik/pen/pbaAxw)

Ignoring the boilerplate used to wait for the scene to load, the code is:

```
var someText = document.querySelector('#someText');
someText.addEventListener('mouseenter', mouseenter);

function mouseenter () {
  someText.setAttribute('bmfont-text', 'text: Hi');
}
```

Where "someText" points to an entity with the [bmfont-text component](https://github.com/bryik/aframe-bmfont-text-component) (though it would work for [geometric text](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-text-component) as well). This example uses [Mayognaise's mouse cursor component](https://github.com/mayognaise/aframe-mouse-cursor-component) but could easily be changed to a gaze-cursor.

-

Additionally, [here is a CodePen demonstrating ngokevin's answer](http://codepen.io/bryik/pen/ZOAJmA). I was going to post this as a comment to his answer, but I don't have enough reputation points...

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [event-set component](https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component) (download the dist and drop into your project), not the animation tag:

```
<a-entity text="text: Hello" event-set="_event: mouseenter; text: Hi"></a-entity>
```

0.2.0 build: https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component/tree/v0.2.0/dist

0.3.0 build https://github.com/ngokevin/aframe-event-set-component/tree/master/dist